# Unable to boot ApiServiceProvider, configure an API domain or prefix in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel-8 as restful api. Also I am using Dingo Package. Initially the url was:

```
http://localhost:8888/myapp/server/public
```

And it was loading correctly.

However, I decided to remove public from the url. So I followed these steps:

1. Rename server.php in your Laravel root folder to index.php
2. Copy the .htaccess file from /public directory to your Laravel root folder.

When I tried to reload the url as:

```
http://localhost:8888/myapp/server
```

I got this error:

> Unable to boot ApiServiceProvider, configure an API domain or prefix

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\server\vendor\dingo\api\src\Provider\DingoServiceProvider.php

protected function registerConfig()
{
    $this->mergeConfigFrom(realpath(__DIR__.'/../../config/api.php'), 'api');

    if (! $this->app->runningInConsole() && empty($this->config('prefix')) && empty($this->config('domain'))) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Unable to boot ApiServiceProvider, configure an API domain or prefix.');
    }
}
```

Even with:

```
http://localhost:8888/mygeapp/server/public/
```

The same error still applies

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Could it be mistyped instead `empty($this->config('api.prefix')) && empty($this->config('api.domain'))`?

Comment: @Tpojka - Which other tool can I use for api versioning in Laravel and how do I go abouth this?

Comment: I can't see relation with original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure to configure your IPI PREFIX in the env file

API_PREFIX=api